# How to modify the padding in CheckButtons?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, padding

I am using `CheckButtons` from `matplotlib.mwidgets` and I would like to know if there is a way to change the space between the checkbox and the label (I believe this is called "padding").

Comment: Can you access the rectangles attribute and manually change the location of the tick boxes (https://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.CheckButtons)?

Comment: Thanks, @Patol75. I used the function `set_width()` from the object `rectangles` and it worked as a workaround.